# entropy change during heat loss

Tags: thermodynamics

When a thermodynamic system gains heat if the heat gain is irreversible then there is a entropy generation along with the entropy transfer..so is there a similar entropy generation associated with irreversie heat loss too?

Comment: $S=k_b \ln \Omega$

Comment: I know the formula for entropy...but i don't see how that answers the question..

Comment: You *can* start from @Mann's comments, but there are two more steps to deal with: (a) understand the character of $\Omega(E)$ for the subsystems, and then (b) Understand the character of $\Omega_\text{total} = \Omega_A(E_A) \Omega_B(E_\text{total} - E_A)$. This leads naturally to one of the many ways of stating the second law.

Answer (score 1):

Irreversible heat loss has the implication there are two systems in contact with heat being transferred irreversibly from one to the other. In this case the total entropy of *both* systems should increase: the entropy of the heat donor system will decrease, and the entropy of the heat-receiving system increases by more than the loss in the first system.

Comment: Yes the entropy..of the system will dicrease due to heat loss but can the dicrease in entropy be calculated by..dQ/t even though the heat loss is irreversible..

Comment: I think it can, reading the second paragraph of [this wiki section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy#Reversible_process)

Comment: i read the paragraph, but i don't think it explains anything about entropy generation..